# Difference between struct, package and class in systemverilog

Tags: verification, system-verilog

The difference between class and struct is straightforward, but where does package fit in wrt the whole scheme. Most of the packages I see have imports from library files and include other sv files in the directory. To be more specific, when are packages typically used in a optimal coding scheme, Is it a better practice to use header files instead if no specific variables are added at that level ? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Packages provide a compilation scope in which types, classes, function, tasks and other declarations can be made. Packages can then be imported in other scopes (either other packages or the top-level compilation unit scope).

I think of packages much like namespaces in C++. They provide an area to compile code in a "packaged" manner which can then be imported and used in other places.

Whether the package consists of declarations immediately within the package file, or come from header files which get `included within the package declaration is just a matter of preference.

The following two are equivalent:

```
// File my_pkg.sv
package my_pkg;
    class my_class;
    endclass
endpackage
```

--

```
// File my_class.sv
class my_class;
endclass

// File my_pkg.sv
package my_pkg;
    `include "my_class.sv"
endpackage
```

Answer (score 2):

Packages, like C++ namepsaces can be used to avoid variable name colisions.

```
package a_pkg;
int value = 100;
class a_class;
  task print;
    $display ("value is %d", value);
  endtask
endclass
endpackage

package b_pkg;
int value = 200;
class b_class;
  task print;
    $display ("value is %d", value);
  endtask
endclass
endpackage

package c_pkg;
import a_pkg::value;
class c_class;
  task print;
    $display ("value is %d", value);
  endtask
endclass
endpackage
```

Here two classes refer to global variables of their own packages, both named 'value'. and a third class chooses to use a global variable from a previous package using 'import'.

Without packages the situation would be like this:

```
int value = 100;
class a_class;
  task print;
    $display ("value is %d", value);
  endtask
endclass

// int value = 100; // can't do... compilation error
class b_class;
  task print; // prints 100
    $display ("value is %d", value);
  endtask
endclass

class c_class;
  task print;
    $display ("value is %d", value);
  endtask
endclass
endpackage
```

Also note that `struct`s are treated somewhat like scalar or array variables. A `class` variable holds just a reference and a `new` call is required to create a `class` object. But `struct` variables like array variables *directly* hold values. These can also be used in synthesisable RTL code.

Note that packages cannot be instantiated and there is only one instance of whatever is declared in a package. They could be seen as the TB equivalent of top-level modules in RTL, i.e. modules which aren't instantiated.